# Extend interface to contain a date type

Tags: typescript, types, interface, extends

I need to extend an interface in Typescript to contain a Date type.

I have tried the following

```ts
interface WithDate {
  [key: string]: Date;
}
```

But when I try to extend `WithDate`, I get the error:

```ts
interface Person extends  WithDate {
  id: number; // Property 'id' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type 'Date'
  name: string;
  date: Date;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this error? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface WithDate {
  [key: string]: Date;
}
```

With this interface you are telling TypeScript that objects implementing this interface can have `string` keys but only `Date` values.

```
const obj: IWithDate = {
  key1: new Date(), // OK because it's a date
  key2: new Date('2020-01-01') // OK, another date
  key3: '2020-01-01' // Error, not a Date
  key4: true // Error, not a Date
  key5: 123 // Error, not a Date 
  // and any other objects besides `Date`s will cause a compiler error
}
```

So when you `extend` the `WithDate` interface, TypeScript sees the index signature and attempts to merge these interfaces, however, there are conflicting shapes here:

`{ id: string }`

and

`{ [k: string]: Date }`

So the compiler tries its best to solve these conflicts and because this is a fairly ambiguous situation, TypeScript has to choose some a shape and it chooses `{ [k: string]: Date }` because this is the most expected/correct behaviour for interface extensions.

You probably intended to do this:

```
interface WithDate {
 date: Date
}

interface Person extends WithDate {
 id: number;
 name: string;
}

const person: Person = {
 id: 1,
 date: new Date(),
 name: 'bob'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But... Is there a way to make the name of the 'date' attribute arbitrary?

Comment: @KEVINGABRIELCABRERAMARRERO, not that I know of without incurring the problems associated with the index signatures, since index signatures having "type-widening" effects.

Answer (score 0):

Name the field in `WithDate`:

```
interface WithDate {
  date: Date; // Note field name : date
}
interface Person extends  WithDate {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```