# How do I interface a dictionary with a method(s) that doesn't return the same type?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I know it's possible to interface a dictionary in the following way:

```js
interface MyDictionary {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

However, the external package I'm using returns a dictionary with a method on it to format the data contained in it for another purpose.

So I would like to interface it by doing something like the following:

```js
interface MyDictionary {
  [key: string]: string;
  formatForSomethingElse(): any;
}
```

However this gives me the following error:

`Property 'formatForSomethingElse' of type '() => any' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.ts(2411)`

As the object I'm interfacing is external and I have no control over it. Is my only option in this instance, to change the dictionary value to type any?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend interface to contain a date type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63071377/extend-interface-to-contain-a-date-type)

Comment: That makes sense, unfortunately as the object is external I don't have the ability to change it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is worth to rearrange your interface a bit to keep the items separately:

```
interface MyDictionary {
  items: { [key: string]: string; };
  formatForSomethingElse(): any;
}
```

Comment: I have no control over the object I'm interfacing as it is external

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

> I think you need to separate `data` and `method` with some depth

### Answer

Terms of software oop `Interface` is some rules or blue print between A component and B component.

And class is `data+method` so it is good usecase to separate `data` and `method`

`[key: string]: string | Function` is not intuitive usecase with oop

### Example

```js
interface MyDictionary {
  [key: string]: string | Function;
  formatForSomethingElse(): void;
}
```

My recommendation is

```js
interface MyDictionary {
  data : {
     [key: string]: string;
  }
  formatForSomethingElse(): any;
}
```

Comment: I have no control over the object I'm interfacing as it is external